# Zurb Foundation change top-bar colour

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am having trouble changing the top-bar section of a Foundation site to a different colour.

I have created a custom style.css for this.

I can change most of the top-bar color but NOT the right hand drop down list side (I don't have a list on the left). Clicking a link on the drop down changes colour of the nav bar but the nav bar component at the top does not change other than this (hope this makes sense?)...

This is the basic HTML:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <a href="#">Sections</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="about.html">####</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="philosophy.html">####</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="beginning.html">####</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">#####</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
         </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <a href="#">Links</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#" target="new">####</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="new">####</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="new">####</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
         </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </section>
```

This is my attempt at changing it using style.css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.top-bar {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}


.top-bar-section ul {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}

.top-bar-section ul.right {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}


.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}


.top-bar-section ul li.active > a {
   background-color: #2D4DC7;

/** Changes the hover state of non active menu items **/
.top-bar-section li:hover a {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}


.top-bar-section ul li > a {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}


.top-bar-section ul.dropdown li a:hover:not(.button) {
     background-color: #2D4DC7;
}


.top-bar-section ul.dropdown {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}


.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
    background-color: #2D4DC7;
}
```

I am pretty sure it is just syntax that I am having issues with. Something to do with the 'right' class I think???

Any help please?

Many Thanks

Comment: I have had a long time changing the color of my top nav bar.. For your dropdown, unfortunately I was happy with the original dropdown colour so I didnt change it..You can check out my website - clickmynotes.com.. I edited the foundation.css only..Feel free to access the css and use it if you want to..I have commented 'lakshay' everywhere I changed something in the file..So you can quickly get all the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use a browser such as Firefox with Firebug installed.

Load any page, hit Tools > Web Developer > Inspector  (or its hot key equivalent), then click on your object, the HTML code inspector will reference the exact line of the css file that is governing the style being generated (either the style directly, or the computed style).

Time and sanity saver.

Comment: Thanks! Never new that existed and it is quite useful!!

Comment: did you track your issue down?

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts and some help from Zurb support the CSS i needed was:

```
.top-bar-section .dropdown li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
      color: white;
      background: #740707;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SCSS/SASS version of foundation you should change the defaultvalues for the topbar.

The defaultsettings are stored in `_settings.scss`.

For example to change it to cornflowerblue I used these settings:

```
$topbar-bg-color: cornflowerblue;
$topbar-bg: $topbar-bg-color;
$topbar-link-bg-hover: scale-color($topbar-bg, $lightness: -14%);
$topbar-link-bg-active: $topbar-bg;
$topbar-dropdown-bg: $topbar-bg;
$topbar-dropdown-link-bg: $topbar-bg;
$topbar-dropdown-link-bg-hover: scale-color($topbar-bg, $lightness: -14%);
```